# Python: Can I combine these functions together to shorten my python code?

Tags: python, function

Can I combine these functions together to shorten my python code? I'm creating a quick program!

Here are the functions:

```
def try1():
        try:
            num1=input("Enter num 1: ")
            return num1
        except ValueError:
            print("incorrect!")
            return #value

def try2():
        try:
            num2=input("Enter num 2: ")
            return num2
        except ValueError:
            print ("incorrect!")
            return #value

def try3():
        try:
            num3=input("Enter num 3: ")
            return num3
        except ValueError:
            print ("incorrect!")
            return #value

def try4():
        try:
            num4=input("Enter num 4: ")
            return num4
        except ValueError:
            print ("incorrect!")
            return #value
```

Please post your suggestions and answers below.

As you can see from my reputations, I am a new programmer hoping to find kind people on Stackoverflow.

Comment: why do you use while-loops if they will only run for 1 iteration?

Comment: and Why four functions that does exactly the same thing???

Comment: Here is the solution::::::def try():
        try:
            num=input("Enter num: ")
            return num
        except ValueError:
            print("incorrect!")
            return #value

Comment: what do you want to actually happen in the except clauses?

Comment: I am wondering why people are answering this question!!!! The shortest way to condense above code is JUST TO WRITE ONE FUNCTION AMONG THOSE ALL...

Answer (score 3):

(This answer is based on the original revision of the question which is no longer accessible but showed a different problem, where the user is keep being asked until a valid number is entered. And the code showed some skill game system or something, so that’s why my questions are longer and more specific too.)

Something like this?

```
def getInt(name, target):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('Please enter {0} for {1}: '.format(name, target)))
        except ValueError:
            print('Incorrect!')

strength0 = getInt('strength', 'character 1')
skill0 = getInt('skill', 'character 1')
strength1 = getInt('strength', 'character 2')
skill1 = getInt('skill', 'character 2')
```

In general, when you have multiple functions that approximately do the same thing, then yes, there is a lot potential to refactor it so you [don’t repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). In this case, what was different is the question the user was being asked, so if we parameterize that, we are good to use just a single function to handle it all.

Comment: Where did strength and skill come from?

Comment: @user2953955 In your original question, you had questions like *“Please enter strength for character 1”* and *“Please enter skill for character 2”*, so that’s where I took it from. Of course with your changed question, you could just parameterize the number, or the whole question the user is presented with.

Answer (score 1):

The function can be generalised to ask for the input of any number, for example:

```
def try_num(n):
    num = int(input("Enter num {} : ".format(n)))
    while num != n:
        print ("incorrect!")
        num = int(input("Enter num {} : ".format(n)))
    return num
```

Use it like this:

```
try_num(10)
Enter num 10 : 9
incorrect!
Enter num 10 : 10
10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def safe_int(x):
   try:
      return int(x)
   except ValueError:
      return 0

[safe_int(raw_input("Number %d:"%i)) for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Please use `except Exception` instead of a bare except handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a validation method and simply pass in the strings.

```
def validate(question):
    while True:
        try:
            print question,
            input = raw_input()
            if input.isdigit():
                return int(input)
            else:
                print "Not a valid integer"
```